# formatresult in jquery is not calling

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

```
 <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
<script>
$("#fname").autocomplete("service/getData.jsp", {
    formatItem: function(rowdata) {
        var details = rowdata[0].split(":");
         return details[1];
    },
    formatResult: function (rowdata) {
        alert("hello");
        var details = rowdata[0].split(":");
        $('#lname').val(details[0]);
        return details[1];
    }
});

</script>
```

Alertbox `formatResult` is not being called, i'm very frustrated. Please Help.!!

**EDIT**

I've referred the code from this link 
[3-steps-to-creating-a-jquery-autocomplete-drop-down-menu](http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/3-steps-to-creating-a-jquery-autocomplete-drop-down-menu/)

Comment: Don't repost questions.  You can add a bounty to give this question more attention.  Read this section in the [faq#bounty].

Answer (score 0):

The `autocompleteopen` event might fulfill your need.

Set the autocomplete like this :

```
$("#fname").autocomplete("service/getData.jsp", {
    formatItem: function(rowdata) {
        var details = rowdata[0].split(":");
        return details[1];
    }
});
```

Now add the `autocompleteopen` event:

```
$( "#fname" ).bind( "autocompleteopen", function(event, ui) {
    var rowdata = $("#fname").autocomplete( "option", "source"); // this line retrives all options provided in the 'source' property of autocomplete
    var details = rowdata[0].split(":");
    $('#lname').val(details[0]);
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryWQu/2/)

Comment: are you sure "service/getData.jsp" is returning some value ?

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ?

Comment: this is the output, when i'm pass "s" into getData.jsp `SOUTH-WEST:SW SOUTH:S SOUTH-EAST:SE`

Comment: Now, i want that, when user select any suggestion, then it's one part let's take `South-West` should be in `fname` and another part that is `SW` will be in `lname`.

Comment: @tusar: This example uses jQueryUI autocomplete, not the plugin the asker is using...

Answer (score 0):

$(function() {

$("#fname").autocomplete({
    source: "service/getData.jsp",

```
formatItem: function(rowdata) { 

    var details = rowdata[0].split(":");
     return details[1];
},
formatResult: function (rowdata) {
    var details = rowdata[0].split(":");
    $('#lname').val(details[0]);
   // return details[1];
}
```

});

});

Try this will work. have added the **source** in it.

~K

Comment: same story... this time it's giving suggestion also...

the output of the getData.jsp when i'm passing "s"  is like this 

`SOUTH-WEST:SW SOUTH:S SOUTH-EAST:SE`. This may help you.